# Can I use a custom distance measure for kmeans function?

Tags: r, k-means

I am using the function, kmeans, to perfrom K-means clustering.

I have a special data which need a custom distance measure function and custom mean function.

Can I put (1) a custom distance measure function and (2) custom mean function to the kmeans function?

It seems it uses Euclidean measure only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard `kmeans` does not allow this, for good reasons. It uses some clever algorithms (Hartigan and Wong; which is why it is *much* faster than the standard Lloyd textbook algorithm you find in about 100 other R packages). But these only work for the classic k-means scenario with squared deviations (which means assigning each cluster to the Euclidean nearest center, but it actually optimizes least-squares, not Euclidean distances).

I doubt you can simply plug in other distances and centroid functions into the Hartigan and Wong method (apart from it being written in Fortran, so you cannot just plug in a R function there anyway).

Beware that there are very *few* known combinations where other distances and means are known to always converge well. Bregman divergences should be fine, and cosine is equivalent to squared Euclidean on a sphere, so it will also work.